# Luck is islam superstition?

Tags: halal-haram

Is breaking a mirror in Islam considered bad luck if so please explain and if not also please explain I’ve heard many different things about this subject most of them rejecting any superstition but no body’s EXPLAINED to me so please and thank you it’d mean alot

Answer (score 4):

According to this hadith:

> "Paying attention to the bad omen (tayyara) is association (shirk). It has nothing to do with us. Allah will remove it by reliance on Him." ([Al-Adab Al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/adab/39/3))

Believing in bad luck (due to anything including breaking a mirror) is shirk.

> "There is no infection and **there are no bad omens**, although I am pleased by a good omen - a good word." ([Al-Adab Al-Mufrad](https://sunnah.com/adab/39/7))

So, there is no "bad luck" involved in the breaking of a mirror (disclaimer: some bad things might happen, namely stepping on the broken glass pieces by accident) nor with anything else.